# C++ Singly Linked List Find Nodes value x spaces from beginning

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

```
float get(int x) {
        if(x == 0) {return head->x;}
        else {
            Node *current = head;
            for(int a=0; a<x; a++) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            return current->x;
        }
    }
```

This is my code, but when I run it with a test case, it says "Lab3.exe has stopped working".  I'm still really new to C++ and our teacher hasn't been helpful in the slightest, can anyone give me advice on my implementation?

EDIT:
Here's the test case...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// including _my copy_ of SLList
#include "./SLList.h"
using namespace ods;

template <class FloatList>
bool listTest(){
    FloatList L;
    L.add(0, 3.14);
    L.remove(0);
    L.add(0, 1.62);
    L.add(1, 2.23);
    L.set(1, 2.72);
    /*float x = L.get(1);*/
    return ( 2.72f == L.get(1) and 2 == L.size() );
}

int main() {
    if ( listTest<SLList<float> >() )
        cout << "SLList passes basic list interface test" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "SLList FAILS basic list interface test" << endl;
}
```

And here's how the SLL is set up:

```
template<class T>
class SLList {
    T null;
protected:
    class Node {
    public:
        T x;
        Node *next;
        Node(T x0) {
            x = 0;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int n;

public:

    SLList() {
        null = (T)NULL;
        n = 0;
        head = tail = NULL;
    }

    virtual ~SLList() {
        Node *u = head;
        while (u != NULL) {
            Node *w = u;
            u = u->next;
            delete w;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're probably running past the end of the list. What is your test case? How do you set up the list? Is there a `tail`?

Comment: In the `for` loop, you might want to check if `current` is `nullptr` (or `0` if your compiler is old) before dereferencing (`current->next`)

Comment: There is a lot of code missing here. Most helpful is a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'd invest some time in learning to use the debugger.